# playonlinux's unmet dependencies block from installing anything

Tags: software-center, package-management

Everytime I try installing `wine` or `playonlinux`, I get this error:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additonal software pachages...
```

Details:

```
the following packages have unment dependencies:

playonlinux
```

This error sometimes appears in different variations.

People on other posts say I need to do a clean install: is this right? I don't want to do so, but if I will have too, I will...

Comment: What happens if you open the terminal and type sudo apt-get install playonlinux? Do you get more dependency errors or does it install ok?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should remove `playonlinux` with `dpkg --remove playonlinux` or install it's dependencies with `apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0):

When ever it says unmet dependency it will also pop up ad box with list of packages that need to be install. Select that and copy it.

Later do a

> apt-get install "PASTE_WHAT_YOU_COPIED - WHICH_WILL_BE_UMET_PACKAGES"